# Sketch for differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine all resting positions for differential equation  $x'=f(x,\mu)$. Examine whether the resting positions are attractive or repulsive.

$x'=x^2-\mu$

Make a sketch in the plane $(\mu,x)$ where the corresponding resting positions are drawn on vertical lines $\mu=const$ and the behavior of the solutions for the respective value are shown with arrays.

Note: Branching diagram.

Solution:

$x=+-\sqrt(\mu)$

$f(x)=x^2-\mu$

$f'(x)=2x$

$f(-\mu)=-2\sqrt\mu$ attractive

$f(\mu)=2\sqrt\mu$ repulsive.

But how do I make sketch?

Answer (score 1):

This is an option

[image]

The dashed line shows that branch is unstable, and the solid line that it is stable

[This](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/simple_plot.html) script will help you generate your own version the plot